# program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

When I am trying to add the tableview in xcode when I click the table item then it goes to the next screen and again when i click the back button and go to previous tableview page and select the table item then it gives the error as program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Enable NSZombie and look for Zombie objects.

Comment: Even before zombies, try "Analyze".

Comment: The problem is a memory management bug in your code.  Fix that and all will be fine.  Want a more specific answer?  Show some code.

Comment: Are you using the NSMutableArray or NSArray?

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *stateSelected = 
    [itemcatg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
               @"You have selected %@",stateSelected];
    [stateSelected release];
    [msg release]; 
    if(itemNames==nil)
    {itemNames=[[Itemnames alloc]init];
    }
    [itemNames setItemcatgory:stateSelected];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:itemNames animated:YES] ;
    [itemNames release];
 }
When I click the back button it gives error here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a memory issue 
it happens when you trying to access an object which is already being released.

Answer (score 0):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS indicate memory issue, you may release object already been released, try enable  NSZombie for further information, add NSZombieEnabled to the "Environment Variables" section in scheme settings.

Comment: Thanksfor responding,ut when I add the NSZombieEnabled to the Environment Variables then also not working.Plz give me solution

Comment: rani, NSZombieEnabled won't fix the problem, it helps you debugging.